# dpkg format file is corrupt

Tags: apt, dpkg, corruption, bodhi

I'm live booting a fresh install of Bodhi Linux and upon my first attempt at using apt-get I'm getting

```
dpkg: error: corrupt info database format file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format's

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned and error code (2)
```

What happened? How do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Remove the default format file

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/format
```

Create a new format file consisting of the following

```
sudo printf "1\n" > /var/lib/dpkg/info/format
```

Comment: sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/printf: Input/output error

Comment: @ArielArévalo Sounds like there are low-level device errors on the media (USB?)